# Ext.ComponentManager nameHolder issue - Uncaught Error: Duplicate name

Tags: extjs

When _fixReference is fixing holder it looks up for name holder me.lookupNameHolder();
but as the parent form (actual name holder for the field) is not registered yet in Ext.ComponentManager holders registry

In this case, markReferencesDirty() is not resetting refs for the name holder correctly
holder.refs = holder.nameRefs = null;

We have Ext.Error:

```
Uncaught Error: Duplicate name: "name" on ext-formpanel-1 
   between ext-textfield-1 and ext-textfield-1
```

Please, check fiddler for working example and possible solution
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3n9p

UPD: add override with possible solution

```js
 Ext.override(Ext.Component, {
   lookupNameHolder: function (skipThis) {
     var cm = Ext.ComponentManager;
     var holder = this.getInheritedConfig("nameHolder", skipThis !== false) || null;
     var id = holder.getId();
     if (!id) return;
     if (!cm.holders[id]) {
       // as we already found the component as a holder
       // it should be added to holders registry
       cm.holders[id] = holder;
       holder.beginSyncChildDirty();
     }
     return holder;
   },
 });
```

Comment: Sounds like a racing issue. If I put `var picker = Ext.create...` into and `Ext.defer`, even with a timeout set to 1 ms, the error is gone.

Comment: 1) `ComponentManager` has a `register` method, it registers components (all and holders) in the order from children to parent. 
2) Form (parent) is nameHolder for a field with name (child). 
3) the parent will be registered after children are registered.
4) Finally, `lookupNameHolder()` breaks this order. 
5) It finds the holder (form) before it is registered by `ComponentManager`.

It seems, `Ext.defer` can be a solution as it is deferring `lookupNameHolder()`, but in my opinion, it is better to register the name holder once it is found with `lookupNameHolder()` if not registered yet.